# When using Agentless Exception Monitoring, do all clients/hosts have to be on the same domain?

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-error-reporting

I recently set up Agentless Exception Monitoring (AEM) in System Center Operations Manager 2012 R2 (SCOM). It works well when the client is joined to the same domain as the management server -- but I've been unable to get it to work when the client is **not** on the same domain (but is on the same network).

I can set up Windows Corporate Error Reporting (WER/CER) via group policy, point it to the server, and everything seems to be configured -- but it's not getting the crash dumps across the network for some reason. Maybe an aside would be if WER/CER produces logs?

For this case, my network is an internal VirtualBox network with a DHCP server running. I can see my server from the client and am able to log into the web console from the client as long as I provide proper domain credentials.

So, my question is:

**How can I configure a client to report exceptions using AEM to SCOM when the computer isn't on the same domain?**

If this is possible at all -- which I hope it is =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get CER working from a client that was not joined to the same domain as the server.

Here are the high level steps I took.

-Setting everything that seemed relevant by using `gpedit.msc` under `Local Computer Policy -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Error Reporting`.

-Set in the registry and set a couple things inside `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting`. I found [this WER Settings MSDN page helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638.aspx) for that. The most important settings seemed to be: `CorporateWERPortNumber` `CorporateWERDirectory` `CorporateWERServer`.

-In addition to setting up all the WER/CER settings I could get my hands on, I also had to configure the DNS server. In the Network and Sharing center, under Change Adapter Settings, I opened the properties of my local network connection, and then set one TCP/IPv4 setting: The Preferred DNS server. The information for this IP was availible in the Server Manager running on the Windows Server 2012 R2 box.

It feels a bit weird answering my own question -- but I guess a good nights sleep did the trick.